# Linux measure network bandwith

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, network-monitoring

I have a one way connection between 2 computers (both Ubuntu).
I am looking for an easy way to find the **max bandwith**.
I need to find the max transfer rate between computer A and computer B without lost packets.
Can someone advice?

Currently i am using [netcat](http://deice.daug.net/netcat_speed.html) for this, but i am looking for a better way.

Comment: What is a "half link" connection?

Comment: I mean for one way connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu-users.html) is good article about bandwitch monitoring.

Here is list of those applications:

- bmon
- bwbar
- bwm
- bwm-ng
- iftop
- iperf
- ipfm
- speedometer
- cbm
- ibmonitor
- pktstat
- mactrack
- MRTG
- Cacti

Personally I recommend using bmon. It's enough for me.

Comment: Good answer, but i dont looking for monitoring. I am looking for a way to find the MAX bandwith without any errors.

Comment: You can't, you have to *test* it in order to get the bottleneck bandwidth.

Comment: @scai in the link that i post in the question they show how to measure with netcat , but the problem there is that you need to stop netcat manually and i dont know how much received and sent, so i am pretty sure that with some hacking like PV or netcat flag it can be done.